# any programmable usb/midi control surface, in which I can program the colors of the pads for feedback control?

Tags: openframeworks, midi-instrument

I am looking for a usb/midi control surface that provides feedback on the surface, most surfaces nowadays have some sliders/knobs/pads and usually the pad buttons are coloured.

Ideally, I would like to be able to control these colours so as to get some feedback from the application that I program and is being controlled by the surface.

Is there any such device?

[This one](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2014/04/100-beatstep-sequencer-controller-everything-want-know/) is a pretty ideal controller as far as programmable inputs is concerned, but the pad colours are not assignable.

Is there some other device you know of / worked with ?

Comment: I've done a lot with the APC40.  It uses standard MIDI messages for control of its lights.  It's also very well documented these days.

Comment: @Brad this is a really nice controller :) , but it tends to be somewhat expensive... if only if was not!

Comment: The Novation Launchpad is cheaper if all you need is buttons.